# Django makemessages doesn't collect javascript string inside of template

Tags: javascript, django, internationalization, translation

The current Django project where this problem occurs uses Internationalization and translation in several ways:

1. In template files, translation of content text In Javascript files
2. located inside the static directory In Javascript functions defined
3. inside of template files

Currently 1 and 2 are working fine without any problems.
Running `Django-admin makemessages -l en` generates translations for the template contents and `Django-admin makemessages -l en -d djangojs` generates translations for strings located in the static javascript files.

I'm currently struggling with number 3 and have not yet been able to find any documentation that directly addresses this use case.

What currently happens is that when I run either of the makemessages commands Django does not find the new strings, when I manually add them to my translation files the translation does work just fine thereafter until I run makemessages again.

Why is makemessages not detecting these translations strings and how can I get it to do so?

urls.py:

```
path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
```

snippet from dashboard.html:

```
{% extends "base/template_base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>

<div>
<!-- some HTML content here -->
</div>

<script>
    <!--Intro JS-->
      function startIntro(){
        var intro = introJs();
          intro.setOptions({
            showProgress: true,
            showBullets: false,
            doneLabel: gettext('intro_done'),
            steps: [
              {
                intro: gettext("intro_dashboard_01")
              },
              {
                intro: gettext('intro_dashboard_02')
              },
            ]
          });
          intro.start();
      }
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Where is the i18n in the template?

Comment: I will expand the example, I believed for brevity it wasn't needed since I mentioned that all other kinds of translations DO work.

Comment: Ah, I see. You're trying to use djangojs in your templates. I don't think Django is capable of extracting those strings by itself.

Comment: It seems like a rather simple use case that isn't too uncommon so I hoped that a solution existed.

Answer (score 0):

Place your script in a .js file, it should work.